# How do I make my discord bot say what I say then delete my message

Tags: discord.py

So I'm making a command that makes the bot say what I'm saying then delete it, any help?

Heres my idea

**I send a message**

**Bot says my message**

**Bot then deletes what I said.**

If anyone knows how please tell me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code does the three things for every single message it receives and has a failsafe built-in so that it only repeats message of non-bots, because otherwise it would fall into an infinite loop:

```py
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot:
        return # the user is a bot, we stop execution here
    await message.channel.send(message.content) # send the message
    await message.delete() # delete the message
```

WARNING:
This code is very unsafe in the sense that if a user tries to mention everyone (even without the permissions) and the bot has the permission to mention everyone, it will mention everyone in its message.

If you want this function with all of its functionality, you may want to use the [Pluralkit bot](https://pluralkit.me/).

If you want this whole functionality put into a command, you might want to check out the [extensions for discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#extensions)